# How to set vertical tabs aligned with radiobuttons dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

[image: LookUp UI]

Unable to set UI as below, using `Bootstrap4` . And also unable to produce radio buttons dynamically. Please help with below UI to structure .

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi please find html,ts,scss

Comment: Please add it to question , I think you forgot to save your changes

Comment: yeah sure will add it